# Wrongly Transferred!

Tags: traceability

If for some reason I made a wrong transfer to an unknown blockchain account, how do I know who is that belongs to?

In the first place I think it is unlikely a "wrong transfer" because the Blockchain address is not something you can make typo error. I am very suspicious how people can transfer my btc out without my authorization.

Many thanks for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "blockchain account"? Is it just sent to a bitcoin address?

Comment: it will be useless to anyone if the bitcoin address is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

> **I made a wrong transfer to an unknown blockchain account, how do I know who is that belongs to?**

In general you cannot readily find out who owns an address.

If the owner of the address is especially careless, a great deal of detective work may allow their identity to be discovered eventually. This is not a trivial process.

---

> **I am very suspicious how people can transfer my btc out without my authorization.**

They don't need your authorization, they only need to have once seen your private-keys. That gives them complete control for all time over any funds subsequently arriving at addresses associated with your private-keys.

As an example, many online-wallets (also called web-wallets or hosted-wallets) give control of your private keys to employees of the hosting service and to anyone who hacks that service. So any dishonest ex-employee might be able to empty your wallet. This sort of thing happens with depressing regularity.

Answer (score -1):

First off, people can't steal your bitcoIN unless your address is compromised or used an unsafe online wallet.

If you sent the address, you will unlikely to know who it is but u can lookup the transaction for it